# libaws++ error occors when use command "make"

Tags: c++

I want to use [FADE](http://ansrlab.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/software/fade/) on my computer. So, I have to use the libaws++, which is a C++ library that allows to communicate with Amazon Web Services.

OK, Here is my problem:

The [website](http://aws.28msec.com/) of libaws++ is unavailable. I used Google to search "libaws++" and only found libaws. I didn't know whether libaws is libaws++. They both used to communicate with Amazon Web Services.  So I download libaws from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libaws/?source=dlp).

Here is the process I install libaws:

1. tar libaws-0.9.2.tar.gz
2. cd libaws-0.9.2
3. cp ~/libaws_patch_for_fade.patch libaws_patch_for_fade.patch (cp the patch to libaws-0.9.2)
4. patch -p2 -i libaws_patch_for_fade.patch
5. mkdir libawsbuild
6. cd libawsbuild
7. cmake ..
8. make

And error occors:

```
    [ 28%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/api/connectionpool.cpp.o
In file included from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/aws.h:                                                                                        26:0,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/connec                                                                                        tionpool.h:22,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/src/api/connectionpoo                                                                                        l.cpp:16:
/home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/sqsresponse.h:124:9: error:                                                                                         a€?uint64_ta€? does not name a type
In file included from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/aws.h:                                                                                 29:0,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/connec                                                                                        tionpool.h:22,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/src/api/connectionpoo  

/home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/sqsresponse.h:124:9: error:                                                                                         a€?uint64_ta€? does not name a type
In file included from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/aws.h:                                                                                        29:0,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/connec                                                                                        tionpool.h:22,
                 from /home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/src/api/connectionpoo                                                                                        l.cpp:16:
/home/lx/Nutstore/cloud/libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/sdbresponse.h:105:20: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
.....
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/api/connectionpool.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/aws.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I searched on Google and stackoverflow and didn't get any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#include <stdint.h>` to the top of those header files.

uint64_t is a standard type and should work just fine.

(Unless of course you are on some weird platform that doesn't support 64-bit integers...)

Answer (score 1):

Just got this compiled with the gnu compiler 4.9.x. With newer versions of the compiler, there are more steps needed to compile libaws.

Here's what I had to do:

1) Add the following line to the header files in libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/*.h, after all of the other include statements:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

2) Add the following line to libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws/aws.h, after all of the other include statements:

```
#include <getopt.h>
```

3) If you're using a recent version of the Gnu C++ compiler, you'll need to modify the CMAKE files to add some flags to the compiler, so that the older C++ syntax used in libaws doesn't throw compiler errors.

Add this line to CMakeCompiler.txt, after all of the other CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS commands, around line 82 (which should be a blank line):

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fpermissive -Wignored-qualifiers")
```

FYI: If you're using the Gnu C compiler, you may need a similar line for the C sections, at the end of the other CMAKE commands. Something like this at the end of the file might work, but I haven't tried it:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fpermissive -Wignored-qualifiers")
```

Once those are done, here are the steps to compile:

```
cd libaws-0.9.2
mkdir libawsbuild
cd libawsbuild
cmake ..
make
```

When this is successful, you also may need to copy config.h from libawsbuild/include to libaws-0.9.2/include/libaws in order for the compiler to find config.h in the place it expects, when you compile whatever code you're writing to actually use libaws. (Although that may just have been the way my personal makefile was configured. Don't quote me on that.)